# How can I get a fixed short exposure ( < 2s) with a GoPro Hero 4 Black?

Tags: exposure, shutter-speed, gopro

Does anybody knows about way to fix or manually set the exposure of a **GoPro Hero 4 Black** (FW HD4.02.02.00.00). I want to set **short exposure** (< 2 sec), so that each shot has the same parameter.

[image: GoPro Hero 4 Black]

There are some [hacks](https://github.com/KonradIT/autoexechack/tree/GoPro/LockPhotoExposure) out for the Hero 3/3+, but so far I could not discover anything which works on a Hero 4 Black. I tried the [autoexechack feature](https://github.com/KonradIT/autoexechack) which is used for all these hacks, but it seems like it isn't supported [any more](https://www.reddit.com/r/gopro/comments/2nejmh/gopro_hacking_faq/) since the FW HD4.02. Are there any information I'm not aware of?

Regards

---

ps: I'm aware of that there is the long time exposure function but these question is about short exposure times for day time photos.

Comment: vtc b/c GoPro is primarily an action video camera. Folks at [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com/) are more likely to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @xiota https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5850/questions-on-photography-using-not-quite-a-camera-cameras?noredirect=1#comment11982_5850

Comment: @Hueco It's been well over three years. No one here is answering. The Q has a better chance at [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com/). Plus, what kind of camera can expose images for only > 2 sec?

Comment: The question was/is about the photo exposure! And there is no answer so far! KonradIT (s. link 'hacks' above) had a solution for an old firmware, but that doesn't work anymore as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new firmware update for the Hero 4. You can set the shutter speed and lock the ISO on videos. With the fixed aperture that gives you manual exposure. Shutter speed Options 30fps: 1/30; 1/60; 1/120 @60fps: 1/60; 1/120; 1/240 @120fps: 1/120; 1/240; 1/480

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could just take a short video and then take a frame from it using VLC or some other program. If you want a faster shutter speed you could enable slow motion. Its not a perfect solution but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This likely will not work as many such simple consumer cameras will provide automatic exposure adjustment and change shutter speed while shooting video.  Frame rate and shutter speed are NOT the same thing.